# Run SurfaceView off UI Thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, surfaceview, ui-thread

My surfraceview is where the majority of my application is and I would like to reduce its lag, thus I have been told to take it off the UI Thread.  Is it possible to run a SurfaceView in an AsyncTask?

Comment: Uh, you can't run the UI off the UI thread. You'll get a CalledFromWrongThread Exception. You could however to all the processing stuff which tells you *where* to draw in a background thread, and then only do the *actual drawing* on the UI thread.

Comment: SurfaceView is meant to be drawn into from a background thread: you can use the lockCanvas() and unlockCanvasAndPost() methods on SurfaceHolder to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to draw into a SurfaceView from an AsyncTask it is not recommended. AsyncTasks can run in a serial queue so you would likely block other tasks. Instead just use a Thread. The SDK contains a sample app called LunarLander which shows how to do this.